# Give an example of cochain maps?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I  don't know what is the example of cochain $ f$ from $A^*$ to $B^*$ such as the map $f^i$  from $A^i$ to$ B^i $ is bijective.

Comment: I corrected (I hope) your text, but cannot understand what the question is?

Comment: I am looking for a bijective cochain map {psi: C* to D* }  such as the map {Psi^i from C^i to D^i} is an bijective but the map  {psi* from  
H^i(C*) to H^i(D*)} is not an injective for any i>=0